# SQL view not querying properly in php

Tags: php, html, sql

I created a view which I am now trying to query but my while loop is not executing which i assume means it is empty. which is weird because when i type the sql straight into mysql it returns results.
my sql query is:

```
$sql  = "select * from v_builds where ID = 2";
$result = EasyGo::query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

EasyGo::query is not the problem - this is just a class function to perform the query
```

when run the sql in my linux environment I get the correct results so It is not an issue with the statement

This is where I am looping over the code
the while loop is not being executed - the die statement isnt happening but the query should be returning results.

When I change the SQL to the following

```
"select * from Display where ID = 2"
```

the output shows

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
      <?php
      $counter = 0;
      
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          $imagePath = $row['imagePath'];
          die("image path is "+$imagePath);
          if ($counter === 0){
        echo "<div class=\"carousel-item active\">";  
          }
          else
          {
         echo " <div class=\"carousel-item\"> ";
          }
  
    echo " <img class=\"d-block w-100\" src=\"build_images/$imagePath \" alt=\"slide\" width = \"250\" height = \"400\">
    </div>";
          $counter++;}?>
    
  </div>
```

I am running mysql on linux and the error log shows the following:

```
Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not executing"? Are there errors? Or just no results? Do you have error reporting turned on? Have you checked the error log? What are you using in the background? MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server...? Which exact PHP library? Too many details are missing.

Comment: I have included what sql i am using and tried to make my question clearer

Comment: Seeing `where ID = 2`, I guess we can assume this statement will fetch _at most_ one record? Well then you _have_ fetched that one already, with `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` directly after you executed the query. So there _are_ no more rows to fetch, when you attempt to fetch a _second_ one with your while loop.